# OpenCv error when initializing camera with VisualStudio C++ 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I'm new to opencv programming, so maybe my question will be very stupid. But i have such problem, i took one sample code, which should enable laptop webcamera to show image in desktop.

```
#include <opencv\cv.h> 
#include <opencv\highgui.h> 

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
Mat image;   //create Matrix to store image
VideoCapture cap;
cap.open(0);     // initialize capture
namedWindow("window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);  // create window to show image

while(1)
{
cap>>image;  // copy webcam stream to image
imshow("window", image);   // print image to screen
waitKey(33);      // delay 33ms
}
return 0;
}
```

But when i'm trying to debug it  i get an error message.

> Unhandled exception at 0x5a16ebe6 in myNewOpenCV.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000018.

But if i put breakpints on

```
cap>>image;
 imshow("window", image);   // print image to screen`
```

and after debuging im taking it off everything work correctly. Maybe someone can help to find a problem. Thanks.

Comment: Don't use things like `while(1)` would be my first piece of advice - you'll need to brutally kill your application to stop it from running, but anyway. Do you mean that once you've cleared all the breakpoints and re-run the program it runs correctly?

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke i dont need to re-run program, if i rerun without breakpoints i get same error. I just continue debuging without breakpoint and it works.

Comment: Sorry, what is the difference between "re-running" and "continuing debugging"?

Comment: please check, if you linked the correct libs, debug build <--> release libs, 32/64 bit, vs-version. as this is a classical dll-hell error.

Comment: Use method cap.isOpened() to check if your camera opened successfully. I think, that you have problem with opening your camera. You can find simple example here: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture